# Am I using Cordova wrong?

Tags: cordova, localhost, wifi

I've never worked with Cordova before so I am totally new into this. My problem is that I've installed Cordova and created project (default hello world app) inside "\xampp\htdocs". Now, when accesing "localhost/myapp/www" in my browser I am getting only endless "connecting to device" message. Alternatively "192.168.1.4/myapp/www" on other devices connected to same local network gives me same message.
So I opened cmd and runned "cordova run browser" command. That resulted into opening "localhost:8000/index.html" in my browser and I got "device is ready" message and that's correct, but when I try to access it from other device like "192.168.1.4:8000/index.html" then it won't open at all and I am only getting "this site can't be reached" error. What am I doing wrong, why can't I access it on other devices?

To clarify what I want to achieve - let's assume I have local network with multiple access points. I need web application that is running on server on same local network and is accessed via browser, and does the following - gets list of AP's within reach of connected device with their signal strength. It should be strictly web application, no deploying as android .apk etc. Cordova with plugins seemed suitable for this, but maybe I just misunderstood Cordova's purpose.  If so, what should I use alternatively?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova it's not a web server, if you need that you can use IIS for Windows ([here a guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site)), or Apache for Linux/macOS ([here a guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/))

Comment: That's what I did first - I created project in "xampp/htdocs/" and I had Apache server up and running. And as I wrote I was able to connect to Cordova hello world app also with other devices, but it hangs on "connecting to device" message. I should get "device is ready", so I guess I am doing something wrong or Cordova doesn't work like this at all.

Comment: Why use cordova then, use a normal HTML, CSS and JS website and it will work because you are serving it from a web server